# How to use regexp for finding patterns in strings?

Tags: c#

I have many patterns that want to find matched string in many string arrays and replace them with "NON" string.
for example, if we have:

```
str[0]={"this","is","a simple","text","for","example","."};
str[1]={"Can","you","help me","please","?","thank","you","very much"};
string[] patterns={"the","that","(eg width)","123",",","text","for example","help me","very much"};
```

Replace matched patterns in str[i] with "NON" is the desire result:

```
str[0]={"this","is","a simple","NON","NON","NON","."};
str[1]={"Can","you","NON","please","?","thank","you","NON"};`
```

How to I can do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are NN and NUN intended ? If so can you provide a rule for this kind of transformation ?

Comment: How is matched the "for example" in your ... example ? in the source string array (str[0]) the word are two different items ?

Comment: I edited them. every match in str replace with NON.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a mutating solution:

```
public void ReplaceStrs(string[] srcStrs, string[] patterns, string changeTo)
{
    for (int i=0; i < srcStrs; i++) {
        if (Array.IndexOf(patterns, toChange[i]) >= 0) {
            srcStrs[i] = changeTo;
        }
    }
}
```

Non-mutating:

```
public string[] ReplaceStrs(string[] srcStrs, string[] patterns, string changeTo) {
     srcStrs.Select(s => Array.IndexOf(patterns, s) >= 0 ? changeTo : s).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, What is toChange? I don't think  your codes solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A one liner just for fun :]

```
str = Array.ConvertAll(str, a => Array.ConvertAll(a, i => patterns.Contains(i) ? "NON" : i));
```